# Add custom datasouce to form in ax 2012

Tags: forms, datasource, axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I want to add a custom relation to datasource into a form in AX 2012.

When i use the option to add datasource as Referenced Datasource the system makes a automatic join with AutoReport field into field group into the table, but i want to get information using another field for join

Example.

I have CustTrans Table and i want the order account name, but when i put the reference datasource only appears the account name and not the order account name.

I don't know if the option with querybuilddatasource works.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [display](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa595058.aspx) method on the `CustTrans` table instead of joining a new data source, e.g.:

```
//BP Deviation Documented
display CustName orderAccountName()
{
    CustTable     custTable;
    DirPartyTable partyTable;    
    select firstonly Party from custTable
        where custTable.AccountNum == this.OrderAccount
        join Name from partyTable
        where partyTable.RecId == custTable.Party;    
    return partyTable.Name;
}
```

Then you can just use this display method to show to order account name on the form.

If you do want to add a new data source and link it using the `OrderAccount` field, you can add the `CustTable` data source as usual (JoinSource = CustTrans, LinkType = InnerJoin or OuterJoin, etc.) and override its `init` method, e.g.:

```
void init()
{
    QueryBuildDataSource qbds;    
    super();        
    qbds = this.queryBuildDataSource();
    qbds.clearLinks();
    qbds.addLink(fieldNum(CustTrans, OrderAccount), fieldNum(CustTable, AccountNum));
}
```